# MRTG installation on centos 7

Tags: centos7, network-traffic, mrtg

I have to monitor traffic on my system. CentOS 7 is installated on system. For that I have found mrtg tool that gives a visual display of traffic also. I have search a lot but could not found guide for CentOS 7 version.

Can anyone guide me its all steps briefly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CentOS 7, you can follow guide [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-linux-multi-router-traffic-grapher-tutorial/). Although it is for older version but I also works on CentOS 7. I could not include all steps here. It is simple just follow the urls.

Comment: Thanks, Finally I was able to configure it